# styling HTML5 section tag differently from div to div

Tags: css

I have a div like this

```
<div class="toogle">
    <section class="toggle active">
        <label>Label 1</label>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <p>Label 1 content..
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="toggle active">
        <label>Label 2</label>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <p>Label 2 content..
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="toggle">
        <label>Label 3</label>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <p>Label 3 content..
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

What it does or supposed to do is not important. So please do not pay much attention to its contents.

To style this, I got some style instructions. And for brevity purposes, I'm only including just a small portion from the style sheet instructions which target that HTML - that I pasted above.  So, here we go.

```
      section.toggle.active > label {
         background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F4F4F4; /* gray color behind the label.*/
         border-color: green;
         color: black; /*label color ( clicked ) */
     }

     section.toggle label {
         border-left-color: #0088CC;
         color: red;
     }
```

As you see, it's just styling the `toggle` classes which are defined in `section` tags.

The question is the following!

What if I place another HTML zone, just like the one I pasted above? Since the style instructions above is generic, both zones will be driven by the same style sheet instructions. Well, what if I want the content to show on a green background in the first HTML zone, and on a red background in the duplicated version of the green.

I thought, maybe a good solution to this would be to wrap these HTMLs into their own divs like this;

```
<div id='greenzone'>
            <!--first HTML zone here--> 
    <div class="toogle">
            <section class="toggle active"> 
            ..
    ...     
</div>
```

and then I can have the redzone as ...

```
<div id='redzone'>
            <!--duplicated HTML zone here--> 
    <div class="toogle">
            <section class="toggle active"> 
            ..
    ...     
</div>
```

I thought that would be the way to go here...

but then when I tried the following, to style them as red and green, it did not work.

```
#greenzone section.toggle.active > label {
         ...
    }

#redzone section.toggle.active > label {
         ...
    }
```

Basically, I just added the `#greenzone` or the `#redzone` to further qualify the stylesheet instruction.

Is there something wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Are you trying to style the background of #greenzone and #redzone or the labels within them?

Comment: Honestly, I'm very lost as to what exactly you need here. By the title- you want each section to be styled differently according to the div that is wrapping it? Why not using the .parent-div.section:nth-child(1,2,3...nth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes here say toogle not toggle did you cut and paste this snippet or retype?

```
<div id='greenzone'>
            <!--first HTML zone here--> 
    <div class="toogle"> <-- TOOGLE
            <section class="toggle active"> 
            ..
    ...     
</div>
```

Comment: Right on the dot. That's just a typo. So my approach was right all along. I just made a typo. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: No worries - happens to me ALL the time ;o)